# Code works on Windows, same code doesn't work on Linux

Tags: php, sql, windows, sqlite

I've got a website I'm developping with PHP5 + SQLite3, It worls like a charm on WAMP on my computer, but for some reason it doesn't work on my Debian Server, I don't get any error, I can access my db via adminer.php, but my own PHP code doesn't seem to be able to access it.

Here are the 2 last lines of the error log :

```
[Fri Jun 20 01:33:37 2014] [error] [client 93.2.64.89] PHP Warning: SQLite3::query(): Unable to prepare statement: 1, no such table: morceaux in /home/sim/www/gaec/sqlite-read.php on line 12   
[Fri Jun 20 01:33:37 2014] [error] [client 93.2.64.89] PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchArray() on a non-object in /home/sim/www/gaec/sqlite-read.php on line 14
```

And here is my DB-test php file :

```
<?php
$dbname='viandes.db3';
$mytable ="morceaux";

if(!class_exists('SQLite3'))
 die("SQLite 3 NOT supported.");

$base=new SQLite3($dbname, 0666); 

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT Animal FROM $mytable WHERE LENGTH(Animal)>0";
$results = $base->query($query);

while ($row = $results->fetchArray())
 {
    if(count($row)>0)
     {
        $title = $row['Animal'];
        echo "</br> $title </br>";
     }
    else
     {
        echo "Can't access $mytable table.";
     }
  }
?>
```

Comment: That's a shame. Good luck fixing it. We obviously can't help, since you've provided **NOTHING** useful, like actual source code

Comment: Then turn up error_reporting, look into the `error.log`, view source, etc. Noone else is able to guess your issue.

Comment: Here are the 2 last lines of the error log :

[Fri Jun 20 01:33:37 2014] [error] [client 93.2.64.89] PHP Warning:  SQLite3::query(): Unable to prepare statement: 1, no such table: morceaux in /home/sim/www/gaec/sqlite-read.php on line 12
[Fri Jun 20 01:33:37 2014] [error] [client 93.2.64.89] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetchArray() on a non-object in /home/sim/www/gaec/sqlite-read.php on line 14

Comment: When you access your database via adminer (on the Debian server) do you see a table called `morceaux`?

Comment: Are you sure your DB file is called `viandes.db3`, all in lowercase? Windows is not case sensitive, so if your file is called say `Viandes.DB3` Windows would open it while Linux will create the new file (as you are using your flags incorrectly)

Comment: Yes, I see it and it is properly populated.

Comment: Yes I checked the case, and it is properly named.

Comment: @Sim: where is the file located (in regard to the script)? Is it in the same directory?

Comment: Yes in the exact same directory.

Comment: @Quassnoi Well the error is `no such table: morceaux`, so I'm assuming the script connected to the database successfully. I suppose it's possible he's connecting to the wrong database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs:

> `public SQLite3::__construct ( string $filename [, int $flags [, string $encryption_key ]] )`
>
> Instantiates an SQLite3 object and opens a
>   connection to an SQLite 3 database. If the build includes encryption,
>   then it will attempt to use the key.
>
> Parameters
>
> `filename` Path to the SQLite database, or :memory: to use in-memory
>   database.
>
> `flags` Optional flags used to determine how to open the SQLite
>   database. By default, open uses `SQLITE3_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE3_OPEN_CREATE`.
>
> `SQLITE3_OPEN_READONLY`: Open the database for reading only.
>
> `SQLITE3_OPEN_READWRITE`: Open the database for reading and writing.
>
> `SQLITE3_OPEN_CREATE`: Create the database if it does not exist.

By passing `0666` you're in fact passing `SQLITE3_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE3_OPEN_CREATE` which would create an empty database if the file does not exist. Those flags are not file permissions.

Most probably your database filename differs in case from that in your code. Windows ignores case and opens the database while Linux creates a new database (and hence cannot find the table your want there).

Comment: Non, the db is named correctly, the same way as written in the code.

Comment: @Sim You can verify by only passing `SQLITE3_OPEN_READWRITE`, which should throw an error, rather than creating an empty database, if the database is not found.

Comment: In fact you gave me the answer, I replaced `0666` by `SQLITE3_OPEN_READONLY` And it worked ! Thank You ! :) 

( I'm new : how do you set the post as resolved ?  )